# Use ajax to draw graph dynamically using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I trying to use highchart's ajax functionality to draw this graph 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/

Here is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/dashboard/graphdata', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var options = $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Column chart with negative values'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: data
    });
    });
});
```

This is the response of http://localhost/dashboard/graphdata

```
"\"\\\"[{name: 'John', data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]},\\\\n            {name: 'Jane', data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]},\\\\n            {name: 'Joe', data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]}]\\\"\""
```

However instead of a graph I'm getting this
[image: Instead of graph getting series]

Comment: Do you have any console errors

Comment: No I don't have any console errors

Comment: Your response looks strange... Why has it these  slashes?

Comment: can you reprodce the same in a jsfiddle

Comment: It looks like you load a txt with json inside. Try to return native JSON in your back-end and then load by ajax. 

How you return json in your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to intialize your high charts then you need to get the value from ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Voting Results'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'votes'
        }
    },
    series: [{}]

};

    $.getJSON('http://localhost/dashboard/graphdata', function(data) {
        options.series[0].name = "Votes";
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

Comment: Keeping in mind you have added the allow cross origin  in your php file

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line below console.log() in your code. It will convert string to json format

```
//data = "\"\\\"[{name: 'John', data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]},\\\\n            {name: 'Jane', data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]},\\\\n            {name: 'Joe', data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]}]\\\"\"";
data = data.replace(/\\+n\s*/g,'');
data = data.replace(/.*?\[/,'[');
data = data.replace(/\}\][\\\"]+$/,'}]');
data = data.replace(/'/g,'"');
data = data.replace(/([a-z\_\-0-9]+)\:/g,'"$1":');
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

We have to make little clean up with the string. Also reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: I get the same output